# Can we add any string with !Ref in cloudformation template?

Tags: aws-cloudformation

I need to add a name after the !Ref in my cloudformation template, I am trying to deploy Java microservice in ecs & want Task should have different names for each microservice.

I tried using !Sub but didn't worked for me.

```
  TaskDefinition:
    Type: AWS::ECS::TaskDefinition
    Properties:
        TaskRoleArn: !Ref TaskExecutionRole
        ExecutionRoleArn: !Ref TaskExecutionRole
        Cpu: 256
        Memory: 512
        Family: !Ref EnvironmentName
        NetworkMode: awsvpc
        RequiresCompatibilities:
            - FARGATE
        ContainerDefinitions:
            - Name: !Ref EnvironmentName
              Essential: true
```

Comment: Please show what you've tried and explain why it did not work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing much context (see comment by @lexicore), I'd imagine [Fn::Sub](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-sub.html) should work for your situation where you want to add some text *after* a Ref.

```
ContainerDefinitions:
  - Name: !Sub '${EnvironmentName}-any-text-here'
```